# How to remove the soft buttons/menu in android ice cream sandwitch?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm developing a personal application, which on full screen should hide the standard menu buttons at bottom pane. Does it require me to put my hand in the OS code?

Comment: What standard menu buttons? Do you mean back/home/menu ?
If so, defently, but which phones are they on screen on, and not in hardware?

Comment: @Anders Metnik Galaxy Nexus and other tablets :)

Comment: TBH i don't think it is even possible in custom roms.
The whole system relies on these buttons.

Comment: Will there be a configuration file to disable the button in the OS package, which i could un jar - change and re jar.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Bmusical!

You can hide soft buttons by this method:

After super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) you should use 
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

But after any of interaction with screen its appears.
This behavior is only in tablet, and to solve this problem you should use work around solutions, as:

[Root device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1886460)

[Install and run Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en)

[Install HideBar](https://github.com/ppareit/HideBar)

update: another free application from Google Play that hides menu/soft buttons [full!screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.tsorn.FullScreen&hl=en)